# Simple Qt Embedded Window Question

Tags: c++, qt, window, embedded

How are you meant to initialise the program using Qt embedded? At the moment I'm using QMainWindow but this means including a lot extra when configuring Qt and makes the applications a lot bigger when compiling them statically.What are you meant to use in place of QMainWindow? I don't need anything like maximise buttons - using a small screen with widgets taking up the entire view with no borders.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `QWidget` without a parent is a window.

If you don't want the things provided by `QMainWindow`, you don't have to use it - you can use any `QWidget` subclass.